# Angular production project can't connect to backend

Tags: angular, docker

i have my docker compose for Angular Container , Spring boot.
through Angular Container  i can get any response with Curl from spring boot , but when i am in angular project it shows this error : error name not resolved
[Image of the error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KHES.png)
[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtDTc.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't mean to sound rude but how do you expect us to solve the issue with zero code and/or debugging details? Please update your question with relevant code.

Comment: yeah i am sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the following setup:

- You desktop PC (where you run `docker-compose up`)
- Container "gdc-back" (your backend)
- Container running your Angular app

When you run curl in your angular container, DNS knows about other containers and they can be resolved by their service name. So gdc-back will work as host name.

Now I assume you open your angular app in your browser, running on your desktop PC.

Problem: Your desktop PC does not know about these docker-compose container names. That's why it's not working in your browser.

From your desktop PC both containers are "localhost" and you have to use port mapping to access your services.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/port/, https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for details.

### Update

From your docker-compose.yml you can see that the port is already mapped:

```
  gdc-back:
    image: gdc-back:1.0
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
    depends_on:
      - gdc-back-mysql
```

So the solution is: Update your angular environment.ts (or where ever you've stored the hostname) and use "localhost:9000" instead of "gdc-back".

Comment: so what is the best solution for this problem ?

Comment: You have to use port mapping, have you read the docs I've linked? After this you'll use something like "http://localhost:8090" where port 8090 is mapped to your gdc-back container.

Comment: to be honest i am so confused today , and i really didn't get your point right , want to see my docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: If you post your docker-compose.yml, people would be able to to provide a more concrete solution ;-) - so, yes pls. edit your post and add your docker-compose.yml

Comment: i added a screenshot of my docker-compose.yml

Comment: Pls. do NOT add screenshots but post your code as text. This way people can copy and modify your code. There's a "format as code" symbol in the editor that will make it look nice.

Comment: Thank you so much , you saved my day , i really didn't think about it from that way , my bad , and thank you again

Comment: Great if it works. Pls. just keep in mind for further posts, that people here don't get paid, so it's expected that you really take some time to explain your problem and add relevant code etc... if you don't do that, you questions will be simply closed. It's some kind of art to post the perfect question ;-)